Python Binance Websocket API Failed With WinError 10060
I've been trying to use python binance websocket api with the code below:
import websocket

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade"

def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('close connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('received message')
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, message):
    print('error detected')
    print(message)

websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error)
ws.run_forever()

Error message as below:
error detected
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
error detected
on_close() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

This question might be a bit stupid (?) because this is my first time trying to use the API. I have searched around the web with no results. Do I have to create an API key first? (I didn't.)
Any help is appreciated.

WinErrro 10060 is a Timeout error.  This would mean that your script is not able to connect to that port.  Possible reasons:  1) service port you specified is incorrect.  2) firewall is blocking that port.

also, the on_close() function seems to be called with 3 arguments on_close(wsapp, close_status_code, close_msg) according to the documentation, but you defined the function to only take 1 argument. You should modify your function definition to accept the other 2 parameters.
